# Derivative of an integral with change of variable

Tags: integration, probability-theory, derivatives, expectation

I want to calculate the following:

$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{\tilde{\tau}=t}^{\infty} \tilde{\tau}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(\tilde{\tau}-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} d \tilde{\tau} $$

where $t$ is a constant and $\tilde{\tau}$ is a random variable with mean $x$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I have that $\tilde{\tau} = x + \sigma \varepsilon$, so I use change of variables and redefine the integral with $u = \dfrac{\tilde{\tau}-x}{\sigma}$

$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{\tilde{\tau}=t}^{\infty} (u \sigma + x)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} d u $$

I break the derivative of the integral into two parts:

$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \sigma \int_{u \sigma + x=t}^{\infty}u\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} d u +  x\int_{u \sigma + x=t}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} d u \right)$$

$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \sigma \int_{u \sigma + x=t}^{\infty}u\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} d u +  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}  x(1-F(t)) $$

$$ \sigma \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}  \int_{u \sigma + x=t}^{\infty}u\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} d u +  1-F(t) $$

According to a colleague the first term will vanish. The reason is that apparently after doing the substitution of variable I now have $u$ as a dummy variable and that taking the derivative with respect to $x$ will be zero. But I defined $u=\dfrac{\tilde{\tau}-x}{\sigma}$. How can the derivative with respect to x be zero?

Comment: Why not apply directly $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{t}^{\infty} \tilde{\tau}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(\tilde{\tau}-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} d \tilde{\tau}=\int_{t}^{\infty} \tilde{\tau}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{-\frac{(\tilde{\tau}-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) d \tilde{\tau} $$ and proceed?

Comment: @Did I forgot to mention that $\tilde{\tau} = x + \sigma \varepsilon$. If I took the derivative directly, wouldn't I end up applying the product rule inside the integral? In that case I would need to apply the substitution mentioned above, I think.

Comment: ?? Sorry but what does your comment even mean? At present, $\tilde\tau$ is simply the integration variable hence one could replace it by any other symbol without changing the integral. You are in effect asking for $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{t}^{\infty} w\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}e^{-(w-x)^2/(2\sigma^2)} dw $$ are you not?

Comment: @Did, yes but in that case $w$ would depend on $x$, that is why I wrote $\tilde{\tau} = x + \sigma \varepsilon$.

Comment: What? This is not what the integral in the question means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bounds were constant your coworker would be correct (the integral is essentially $\int_a^b f(u)\mathrm{d}u$, which won't have dependence on $x$ for constant $a,b$.).  They aren't constant though.  We have the lower bound is $u\sigma+x = t$ for $t,\sigma$ constant.  So, we can rewrite this as $u = \frac{t-x}{\sigma}$.  So, your lower bound is a function of $x$, so the derivative isn't necessarily $0$.

As an easy example of how variable bounds can lead to nonzero derivative, consider:
$$F(x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t = e^{-x}$$
We get that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x) = -e^{-x}\neq 0$, with reasoning similar to why your derivative is likely nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

If we use the Leibniz rule for integration we find,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{a(u(x))}^{\infty}f(u(x))du=\big[\int_{a(u(x))}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(u(x))du\big]-f(a(u(x))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(a(u(x))$

The general form of the Leibniz rule for integration is,

$\frac{d}{d t} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x,t)dx=\big[\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(x,t)dx\big]+f(b(t))\cdot \frac{db(t)}{dt}-f(a(t)\cdot\frac{da(t)}{dt}$

I believe the first equation I wrote is correct. This is just application of the chain rule to integral limits which depend on the variable of integration. You should be able to use this to find out whether the integral is zero or not. But as another commenter said, in general it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

$$S={\sigma\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t-x\over \sigma}^\infty ue^{-{u^2\over 2}}du={\sigma\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\left({t-x\over\sigma}\right)^2}^\infty e^{-{y\over2}}d\left({y\over 2}\right)\\={\sigma\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{-{y\over 2}}\right]_\infty^{\left({t-x\over\sigma}\right)^2}={\sigma\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{-{{(t-x)^2\over2\sigma^2}}}\right]$$

So $${\delta S\over \delta x}\neq 0$$.

Comment: You are replacing $\tilde\tau$ by $u$ and $\tilde\tau-x$ by $u$, simultaneously?

Comment: @Sophie Where did I say it is equal to $0$?

Comment: @Did I didn't get you. Please elaborate

Comment: Please explain in detail the change of variable leading to $$\int_{t-x\over \sigma}^\infty ue^{-{u^2\over 2}}du$$

Comment: @ I must be blind, I completely missed its $\neq$, not =. Sorry about this.

Comment: @Did I didn't make the change of variable. I just copied the first integral from the OP's work and instead of $\sigma u+x=t$ , I wrote $u={t-x\over \sigma}$